# IBAction float, have a equal different numbers depending on input

Tags: xcode, floating-point, ibaction

New to objective-c and I just can't find the answer to this question anywhere. I'm running a IBAction for a calculation but I need the input from a label to actually equal something else in the equation.

For example:

```
-(IBAction)calculate; {
  float a = 1.05 if ([label1.text] == 1in);
        a = 2.07 if ([label1.text] == 2in);
        a = 3.07 if ([label1.text] == 3in);
  float b = a*([textField1.text floatValue]);
        label2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", b];
  }
```

I know I'm not even close to getting it right but I hope you get the idea as to what I'm looking for.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, and your code sample makes no sense and is not in correct syntax. Can you try to explain again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)calculate {
  float a;
  if ([self.inputField.text isEqualToString:@"1in"])      a = 1.05f;
  else if ([self.inputField.text isEqualToString:@"2in"]) a = 2.07f;
  else if ([self.inputField.text isEqualToString:@"3in"]) a = 3.07f;
  else a = 0.0f;

  if (a) {
    float b = a * ([self.inputField.text floatValue]);
    self.inputField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", b];
  }
  else self.inputField.text = @"Invalid";
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  //...

  self.inputField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 20.0f, 300.0f, 30.0f)];
  [self.inputField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
  [self.view addSubview:self.inputField];

  UIButton * doneButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 55.0f, 300.0f, 30.0f)];
  [doneButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  [doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(calculate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.view addSubview:doneButton];
  [doneButton release];
}
```

Note: I replaced the output format `%2.f` to `%.2f`, cause I guess you may need this format. E.g:

```
Input > 1in
Output< 1.05

Input > 2in
Output< 4.14

Input > 3in
Output< 9.21
```